# map random numbers

Tags: c++, c

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
   for(int j=0;i<6;j++)
   {
      cout<<rand()%6<<"," // Store these numbers in a map
   }
cout<<endl;
```

Say, suppose I store these random numbers in the inner for loop in a `map<int,myRandomNumbers>`

In some random game, game maker also created a similar call to `rand()%6` to get all 6 numbers. Are these 6 numbers having any slightest chance to be fully or partially the same as one of `myRandomNumbers` ?

Comment: Since they are random, yes, they have precisely that: the slightest chance of being the same. But what is the issue exactly? They are actually the same and you wonder why? Or a different problem?

Comment: both are going to contain a subset or all the numbers of 0-5..

Comment: How do you know that they are the same ?

Comment: @jogojapan, as the numbers are in the range 0 to 5, the probability of both getting the same sequence isn't _that_ slight (to be precise, 1 in $6^6 = 46656$).

Comment: @vonbrand It all depends on how much 'slight' is, and I hope we are not going to discuss this now.... But is the question really whether two random sequences can sometimes be the same? What sort of question is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can calculate it, assuming `rand()` gives a completely uniform distribution (it doesn't, but we'll assume it does anyway). If you generate 6 random numbers in the range `[0, 5]`, the probability that another set of 6 random numbers generated from the same range are exactly the same is `(1/6)^6 ~ 2.14e-5`. You can use the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to calculate the probability that they will be partially similar, that is, match in `n` places for n in `[0, 6]`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you seed the `rand()` function by calling `srand()`, there's a good chance that you will get exactly the same numbers (assuming the random numbers are created by different processes, that is).